# md-datepicker always one day off

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

Hey I have a problem with md-datepicker and can't find solution.
For example I am choosing 2017-05-02 but I am getting   2017-05-01 22:00:00

There is my html

```
<md-input-container flex="50">
    <label>test</label>
    <md-datepicker ng-model="test.deadline" md-placeholder="Choose date"></md-datepicker>
</md-input-container>
```

Angular part.

```
 $scope.deadline = '';
 $scope.$watch('deadline', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (!newVal) {
        return false;
    }
 });
```

I am inserting it into datebase and always have one day off I know that is timezone issue but I can't fix that.

I tried smth like that

```
 $scope.$watchCollection('deadline', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        var test = (moment.utc(newValue.date));
        console.log(moment(newValue.date).format('L'), true);
    )
};
```

But getting error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'utc' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can do with moment.js,

```
 $scope.getdate =function(){
    console.log($scope.myDate);
     $scope.myDate =moment($scope.myDate).format('DD-MMM-YYYY');
  }
```

Check this [`DEMO`](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wel4YBGIofYJYK3OxfAu?p=preview)

Comment: Your demo gave me: "2017-02-23T23:00:00.000Z" While I choosed 2017-02-24

Comment: @RobertNiegowski nope click the button get date and see

Comment: but while my ng-model is for example ng-model="test.myDate" how can I set it?

Comment: @RobertNiegowski check thos updated demo http://plnkr.co/edit/Wel4YBGIofYJYK3OxfAu?p=preview

Comment: something is wrong cause when I am choosing 25.02.2017 I get current date 22.02.2017